# Initialize function pointer array in constructor initializer list - error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers, initializer-list

I am trying to implement a simple menu class, for flexible usage when programming AVR boards. Thus, I cannot use several commonly used STL files (e.g. `functional` or `initializer_list` etc.).

My menu object has pointers toward the previous and next object, but also function pointers that is executed in certain situations. I have issues with these pointers.

I managed to get everything working with one single function pointer. However, when trying to use an array of function pointers I can't find a way to initialize it. Please see minimal example below or on [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/B1GjNpi98). For simplicity, I hard coded the array size to 2.

---

**Error Message**

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘void (**)()’ to ‘void (* [2])()’
```

*Why does the same syntax `tFcnPtr[2]` give two different types??*

The constructor parameter becomes `void (**)()`, while the member is defined `void (* [2])()`.

---

**Function pointer typedef**

```
typedef void(*tFcnPtr)();
```

**tMenu class** (which works fine!)

```
class tMenu {  
  public:

    tMenu(tFcnPtr ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}

    void run() {
        _ptr();
    }

    tFcnPtr _ptr;
};
```

**tMenu2 class**, which does not work. I cannot successfully initialize the function pointer array.

```
class tMenu2 {
  public:

    tMenu2(tFcnPtr ptrs[2]) : _ptrs(ptrs) {} // error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘void (**)()’ to ‘void (* [2])()’

    void run() {
        for (auto& fcn : _ptrs) {
            if (fcn != nullptr) {
                fcn();
            }
        }
    }

    tFcnPtr _ptrs[2];
};
```

**Test**

```
// Main test function
void p(const char c[]) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

// Main
int main()
{
    // Test functions
    tFcnPtr yup = [](){p("Yup!");};
    tFcnPtr zup = [](){p("Zup!");};
    tFcnPtr meh = [](){p("Meh.");};

    // tMenu
    tMenu m1{yup};
    m1.run();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // tMenu2    
    tFcnPtr ptrs[] = {zup, meh};
    tMenu2 m2{ptrs};
    m2.run();
}
```

Comment: There are no function parameters of type array in C++. You may write it as such but the compiler will silently decay the type to a pointer instead. That's an inheritage of C which was taken over into C++. You could make the array a reference type, e.g. instead of `int a[2]` (decays to `int *a`) you could write `int (&a)[2]`. (References don't exist in C and were added in C++.) More convenient and C++-ish would be to use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Good tip on the reference, did not know it worked for functions and methods. It is unfortunate that she::array is not supported by the compiler I use (avr-gcc/WIN-AVR).

Answer (score 1):

In fact the [function parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list) `ptrs`'s type is not an *array*, but *pointer* (i.e. `tFcnPtr *`), which can't be used to initialize an array directly. That's what the compiler complains.

> The type of each function parameter in the parameter list is determined according to the following rules:
>
> 2) If the type is "array of `T`" or "array of unknown bound of `T`", it is replaced by the type "pointer to `T`"

You can initialize the array member as

```
class tMenu2 {
  public:

    tMenu2(tFcnPtr ptrs[2]) : _ptrs{ptrs[0], ptrs[1]} {}

    ...

    tFcnPtr _ptrs[2];
};
```

Or use `std::array` (or `std::vector` if the size is not fixed) instead.

```
class tMenu2 {
  public:

    tMenu2(std::array<tFcnPtr, 2> ptrs) : _ptrs(ptrs) {}

    ...

    std::array<tFcnPtr, 2> _ptrs;
};
```

Comment: Oh, all right. That was a good explanation. Thank you! What I want is a flexible type, which allows different number of pointers.  I don't think std::array is supported (my compiler can't find <array>), so I guess I have to create my own container. No biggy, but maybe buggy?

Comment: @Smartskaft2 `std::array` is supported since C++11, if you can't use it, I think it's a good idea to use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: if `std::array` is not supported, I hardly doubt `std::vector` is. Especially since dynamic memory is a big no-no on these chips (not much heap memory available).

Again, this is not the standard GCC compiler. avr-gcc only supports parts of C+11, not much from STL is supported.